# Migrating a blog... will share button counts change?

Tags: migration, share

I am going to migrate a Wordpress blog from a Wordpress.com account to a privately-hosted server, and neither the domain name nor the permalinks structure will change. Can I expect the numbers indicating share counts to remain intact for my Facebook, Twitter, and Google+ share widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not migrated a site with Twitter or Google+ buttons, but in my experience the Facebook 'like' count has not been affected by moving to a standalone Wordpress installation.

I think as long as the domain name is the same, the widgets are not even aware of the change of setup.

Comment: That is my suspicion as well. Furthermore, as I understand it, the Twitter share widget retrieves it's number from a Twitter search on the page it is on, so I would not _expect_ that one to change either.